# Joomla modules conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, mootools, joomla2.5

I am working ot his project:

www.eltotaldesign.com/planeteco

I have the modules dj image slider, and another named altra switcher.
I tried to install Easy Jquery, and other methods, but nothing helps.
It's 100% problem with jquery and mootols conflict, but I cannot resolve it.
It's there any scripts to resolve this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve those compatibility issues you can try:

- Always load Mootools before Jquery
- Always load and use Jquery noconflict
- Make sure you load those libraries just once per page
- Don't load any of them if you aren't going to use it
- Be careful with joomla cache and when combining js files
- Use carefully any extension that gives you some control on js libraries:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/site-performance

http://www.joomlabamboo.com/joomla-extensions/jb-library-plugin-a-free-joomla-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Do you need mootools on the front end of your joomla install?

If not remove it! It will save your visitor from having to load two libs to view your site:

http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/Issue-Feb-2011/item/349-removing-mootools

If you require both make sure any mootools is using the preferred document.id instead of $ as well as setting jquery in noConflict mode.

Hope this helps! Post back the results.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to use more than one javascript library for extended functionality. Two most popular libraries are mootools and jquery. They conflict because mootools is a prototype and jquery is not. But there is a simple technique to fix this. you can use them both without a conflict.

You just need to take 2 precautions.

1. Add jquery in no conflict mode. It ensures that more than one jquery library can be used simultaneously.

   ```
     jQuery.noConflict();
   ```
2. Include all your jquery code as below

   ```
   (function($){         
     //jquery code goes here.         
    })(jQuery);
   ```

See the complete code.

```
   //no conflict jquery
   jQuery.noConflict(); 
   (function($) {
       //jquery code goes here.
    })(jQuery);
```